# listing all processes in iOS 5.0.1

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, bash

How could one go about viewing all the processes in an ssh session to my (jailbroken)iphone? I'm currently able to ssh in, I have bash installed, core utilities installed, shell-cmds package installed and the system-cmds package installed.

I would have expected the "ps" command to be available from the core-utilities package, but this does not seem to be the case. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the package Cydia package adv-cmds contains a copy of PS

Comment: There's also a package that contains top.